# show/draw path dynamically based on label coordinates

Tags: vb.net

does anyone know how to connect points of a label? Let's say I have a label and start the label at point 0,0. Aterwards, the points jumps to 3,6 ... then to 6, 9 dynamically based on incrementing 3.  How do I show for example, the path it takes to let users know where they are? for example, 0,0 --> 0,3 --> 3,6 --> 6,9 --> etc. I've tried with drawline but unfortunately, this leaves my lable in a mess.

Comment: Are these labels pointing to each other, or are the labels moving, and you are trying to show where it was.  Picture might help.

Comment: @LarsTech - It's just one label and when the mouse hover over the label it changes coordinates. Therefore, that's why I want to connect the coordinates/points.

Comment: You're making your readers guess too much what you are trying to do.  If I hover the mouse over a label, it moves 3 pixels to the left and 3 pixels down?  And you just want to draw a line from where it was to where it is?  Out of curiosity, why is a label moving when someone hovers over it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is draw it in form OnPaint method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 3, 6);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 3, 6, 6, 9);
}
```

Comment: are those parameters by default (0, 0, 100, 100)? does the onpaint automatically paint? how would i pass in what my points(coordinates) are?

Comment: No! this is sample, you have to draw your custom line.I edit that.